# How to uninstall VLC player in MAC OS

Tags: macos

I have uninstalled VLC player in MAC by moving the VLC.app from Applications folder to Bin (and emptied the Bin).

But when I right click a video file and select 'Open With' then I still see VLC.app in the list and I am also able to play videos using the VLC.app.

How do I remove the software from MAC completely?

Comment: Did you empty trash & reboot yet?

Comment: I did not reboot yet but emptied the bin

Comment: Restart has resolved the issue.